# How to execute a unix executable file with Swift

Tags: swift, macos

I developing a OS X application with swift. I need to use some library on my application. The library is a Unix executable file.
I can execute the Unix executable file on terminal.

This is example:

```
pngquant --quality=65-80 test.png
```

But I need execute the Unix executable file on OS X application. I don't know how to do it.

I think should execute command on OS X application, and find an awesome library to execute the command.

Using [swiftline](https://github.com/Swiftline/Swiftline) example:

```
let result = run("ls -all")
print(result.stdout)
```

Print content:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  6 DevinShine  staff  204 Dec 23 22:18 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 DevinShine  staff  102 Dec 23 22:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 DevinShine  staff  102 Dec 23 23:25 Pion.app
drwxr-xr-x  4 DevinShine  staff  136 Dec 23 22:18 Pion.swiftmodule
drwxr-xr-x  7 DevinShine  staff  238 Dec 23 22:18 Pods.framework
drwxr-xr-x  7 DevinShine  staff  238 Dec 23 22:18 Swiftline.framework
```

I copy Unix executable file to Build Phases.

[image: look picture]

But I don't know how to move Unix executable file to OS X application and execute it.

Please help me,thx.

Comment: @Duston I have no idea. I try add unix executable file to "Build Phases". But 
I do not know how to do next.

Comment: you can inspire  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420706/how-to-catch-error-when-setting-launchpath-in-nstask/34420878#34420878

Comment: @user3441734 thx your answer. Swifty provides a quick, concise way to run an external command and read its standard output and standard error.I already post my answer

Comment: i didn't know about Swiftline. did you try to execute some non existent command?

Comment: @user3441734 I try to execute some non existent command. It will print error info

Comment: thank you, will check it ....

Answer (score 3):

I resolved it. The way is easy.

I run my application and execute **run("pwd")**

```
let result = run("pwd")
print(result.stdout)
let fullPath = result.stdout + "/Pion.app/Contents/MacOS/pngquant"
```

print content:

```
/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pion-ebbvaypzstbbordxhgeutzopihtt/Build/Products/Debug
```

excute pngquant function:

```
run(fullPath + " /Users/apple/Documents/test.png")
```

**Update** at 2015-12-25

NSBundle.mainBundle().executablePath will give you the path to your .app wrapper, so code is very clear.

```
run(NSBundle.mainBundle().executablePath + "pngquant /Users/apple/Documents/test.png")
```

Comment: where do you get "run()" from? it's not in AppKit or anything .-.