# Run shell script from Package.swift

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to include a hardcoded version string generated by `git describe` within a CLI I'm writing in Swift.

The idea was to have a shell script that executes `git describe` and writes that as a global constant into a file called `Version.swift`, which I can then reference from within my tool.

I don't want to have to think about running this script before every build though or building the project via another shell script. The ideal way would be to keep using `swift build` and having Swift itself invoke said script when it compiles and evaluates `Package.swift`.

So I included the following in my package manifest.

```
import Foundation

let task = Process()
task.launchPath = "./"
task.arguments = ["update_version.sh"]
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()
```

Whilst importing Foundation and initializing the task seems to work just fine, actually launching it crashes and outputs the following stack trace.

```
error: manifest parse error(s):
2017-07-28 15:07:43.711 swift[39828:16163314] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't posix_spawn: error 13'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9be232cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffb0c5d48d objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9bea1c3d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff9d84c54e -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:] + 3134
    4   ???                                 0x0000000109ccb1c3 0x0 + 4459377091
    5   swift                               0x00000001045fe84f _ZN4llvm5MCJIT11runFunctionEPNS_8FunctionENS_8ArrayRefINS_12GenericValueEEE + 655
    6   swift                               0x0000000104604ab3 _ZN4llvm15ExecutionEngine17runFunctionAsMainEPNS_8FunctionERKNSt3__16vectorINS3_12basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEENS8_ISA_EEEEPKPKc + 707
    7   swift                               0x00000001039f4512 _ZL14performCompileRN5swift16CompilerInstanceERNS_18CompilerInvocationEN4llvm8ArrayRefIPKcEERiPNS_16FrontendObserverEPNS_20UnifiedStatsReporterE + 22802
    8   swift                               0x00000001039ed394 _ZN5swift15performFrontendEN4llvm8ArrayRefIPKcEES3_PvPNS_16FrontendObserverE + 7332
    9   swift                               0x00000001039a2ad8 main + 12248
    10  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fffb1542235 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
0  swift                    0x0000000107073eaa PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x00000001070732e6 SignalHandler(int) + 662
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fffb1751b3a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00000003ba442240 _sigtramp + 147785504
4  libsystem_c.dylib        0x00007fffb15d6420 abort + 129
5  libc++abi.dylib          0x00007fffb012c84a __cxa_bad_cast + 0
6  libc++abi.dylib          0x00007fffb0151c4f default_unexpected_handler() + 0
7  libobjc.A.dylib          0x00007fffb0c5f6fe _objc_terminate() + 103
8  libc++abi.dylib          0x00007fffb014ed69 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
9  libc++abi.dylib          0x00007fffb014e9f2 __cxa_rethrow + 99
10 libobjc.A.dylib          0x00007fffb0c5d94a objc_exception_rethrow + 40
11 Foundation               0x00007fff9d84c884 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:] + 3956
12 Foundation               0x0000000109ccb1c3 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:] + 1816656051
13 swift                    0x00000001045fe84f llvm::MCJIT::runFunction(llvm::Function*, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::GenericValue>) + 655
14 swift                    0x0000000104604ab3 llvm::ExecutionEngine::runFunctionAsMain(llvm::Function*, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, char const* const*) + 707
15 swift                    0x00000001039f4512 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 22802
16 swift                    0x00000001039ed394 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 7332
17 swift                    0x00000001039a2ad8 main + 12248
18 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fffb1542235 start + 1
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -interpret /Users/kilian/dev/apodidae/Package.swift -target x86_64-apple-macosx10.10 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -I /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/pm/4 -swift-version 4 -module-name Package -lPackageDescription -- -fileno 5
```

The content of `update_version.sh` is the following

```
echo "// THIS FILE IS AUTO-GENERATED\npublic let VERSION = \""$(git describe)"\"" > Sources/target/Version.swift
```

What could I do here to get this to work? Does this have to do with the package manifest being executed within a sandbox? And if so, what options do I have to accomplish what I'm trying to do? If in any way possible I'd really love to just run `swift build` and have the rest *just work*.

Comment: Have you considered a `makefile`? You could setup a build rule that runs your script and then invokes `swift build`.

Comment: I haven't. That would actually make more sense than a custom buildscript, but goes into the same direction. But thanks for the suggestion anyhow, a makefile seems like a sane fallback.

Answer (score 0):

the exception has NOTHING with your approach, the system raised it because your launchPath is NOT a valid launch path :-). You have to be ABSOLUTELY sure about the validity of your launchPath, otherwise, the execution will be terminated with some uncaught exception. For a solution see [how to solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34420878/3441734)